# Oracle Apex: files stored in BLOB column not accessible after session expired

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have Oracle Apex app to upload files. Files are loaded by P14_FILE_BROWSE item and storage type is set to apex_application_temp_files. After upload button is pressed process with following PL/SQL code is executed:

```
declare 
begin
 insert into files(

              ID, NAME, FILENAME, MIME_TYPE, CONTENT )

       select ID, NAME, FILENAME, MIME_TYPE, BLOB_CONTENT

       from   apex_application_temp_files

       where  name = :P14_FILE_BROWSE;
    end;
```

I have created report with this table and column ID is defined as URL link p?n=#ID# . I am able to download my files by this link. It works fine until my session expire. When session expire files are no more accessible (The webpage cannot be found). But files are still stored in files table as you can see here:

[files table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQj9D.png)

Why my files are no more accessible by p?n=.. after session expire ? I am using Oracle 12c with Oracle Apex 5.1.

Thank you

Comment: "temp" stands for "temporary". The idea is that it's a temporary holding area for files - you need to copy them elsewhere before the session ends.

Comment: This i now i copy data to table "files." . There was other problem. After session expired data were not more accessible by p?n= link. But there is no problem to access data with download blob content column type.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39143/toc.htm#HTMRN264

"Any select, update or delete operations on WWV_FLOW_FILES should be changed to using the APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES table. Deletes are no longer necessary, as **the file will automatically be purged after the request or when the session is purged**."

Comment: but i have inserted my files into my table "files" . Files in apex_application_temp_files are purged automatically when my session end but they are still in my table "files." I can see them there but they are not accessible. Why? Or this is not right way to pernamently store data?                                                                              Edit: i have used Download BLOB type column instead of link p?n=#ID# and it works

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion:
When you define the link to the report based on the file you uploaded , do include the session and debug id.

example:

'f?p=&APP_ID.:'|| PAGE_ID || ':&SESSION.::&DEBUG.::::'

This be the link to a page (PAGE_ID ) of the application having app_id(APP_ID)

here, 
PAGE_ID is a report page and this report is based on a file uploaded using file browser.
When I had missed out to include the session and debug id , I too couldn't find my report page in a new session.